How can I get tables and fields used in a query SQL from Trino?
Is there a way to get the tables and fields used in a trino query SQL.
Here is an example SQL:
SELECT a.*, b.city_name
FROM ads.test_table1 a
JOIN dim.test_table2 b ON aa.city_id = bb.city_id
WHERE b.zip_code IS NOT NULL

What I need is:



Table
Fields




ads.test_table1
*


dim.test_table2
city_name, city_id, zip_code



Thanks for your help
I'm working on a Java Backend Application and all I have is Trino JDBC Connection.
I searched on Google, and found io.trino.sql.analyzer.Analysis has a tableColumnReferences that is exactly what I want. But I don't know how to get the result from a JDBC Conneciton.
